# LINQ - Group By with Having?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a db table which is having data like below.

```
Name   Tool   Security  QUANTITY    PRICE
  ABC      ML      XXX     100         50      
  ABC      DB      XXX    -50          50      
  XYZ      CS      YYY     30          30
```

My requirement is to group the name and security and pick only that record which is having both negative and positive quantity. In T-SQL this is my query which is perfectly fine. Need similar in LINQ. For example in above it will give both rows for ABC & XXX.

```
select t1.* from MyTable as t1
inner join
(
    select Name,Security  from MyTable 
    group by Name, Security  
    HAVING min(Quantity)<0 and max(Quantity)>0
) as t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name and t1.Security  =t2.Security
```

This is my inner query but it's not working.

```
var Positions = from r in lstpositions
                                  group r by new { r.Name, r.Security} into grp
                                  where grp.Min(x => x.Quantity<0) && grp.Max(x => x.Quantity >0)
                                  select grp;
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your query does not work is because you taking the min of the result of the comparison.

However I think you want `any()` not min and max

```
  where grp.Any(x => x.Quantity<0) && grp.Any(x => x.Quantity >0)
```

This will check for any value below 0 and any value above 0.  It will short circuit so it does not have traverse the entire list which should make it faster.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not realized that I should try any.

Answer (score 0):

Or this

```
where grp.Min(x => x.Quantity) < 0 && grp.Max(x => x.Quantity) > 0
```